# Reshape array in Postgres?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a 1-dimensional array of values in Postgres, such as:

```
[ "1", "4", "2", "5", "3", "6" ]
```

Is there a way to change this to a 2-D array?

```
[ ["1", "4"], ["2", "5"], ["3", "6"] ]
```

Now the dimensions are 3x2 instead of 1x6.

Comment: Did you try a cast? `AS int[2][]`?

Comment: @Bergi: that's bright, but it [does not seem to work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7571c44b8973d5a50ac41897f2ddc782).

Comment: What if there is an uneven number of elements in the array?

Comment: @GMB Guaranteed not to be. Really what I'm trying to do is the last step of a transpose (it's a CodeWars problem where I can't see the solution). Since I wrote this I actually figured out how to get the transpose to work bypassing this particular step, but I'm still curious if there is a good way to do `reshape` essentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two aggregates:

```
select array_agg(arr order by ord)
from (
    select (ord+ 1) / 2 as ord, array_agg(arr) as arr
    from unnest(array[1,4,2,5,3,6]) with ordinality as u(arr, ord)
    group by 1
    ) s
```

or an array constructor:

```
select array(
    select array_agg(unnest)
    from unnest(array[1,4,2,5,3,6]) with ordinality
    group by (ordinality+ 1) / 2
    order by (ordinality+ 1) / 2
    )
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ca5282db8ea95e4daa44d8008537fd77)